# Error in creating Druid datasources from Hive

Tags: hive, druid

Have followed Druid documentation https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Druid+Integration.

The error I am facing is:-

```
 Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
 In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
 set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
 In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
 set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
 In order to set a constant number of reducers:
 set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: 
 /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-druid-handler-2.3.0.jar
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1530)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1523)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1
```

The error saying is unable to find "/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-druid-handler-2.3.0.jar" Although I am using hive hive-2.3.2.
In order to overcome the above problem have downloaded jar and restarted Hadoop. But it is not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Hive1. All the druid integration is done with Hive2.

Comment: I am using hive2  ==>hive --version
==>Hive 2.3.2

Comment: Add /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-druid-handler-2.3.0.jar to the hdfs path